# Would you rather to use Facade or Factory for task based solutions desi

Tags: java, design-patterns

Lets assume you want to create a system or user generated task based on the things that needs to be done in your company 
(Example : send a job for Sales dept to schedule a meeting with vendor) .
You may have a queue of tasks waiting for the creation process(User creates the first task, then System generates other tasks for other departments) based on the user request or you may have a simple task for a department to accomplish a single job.

Would you rather to use Facade , Factory or ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think your question is too broad. Without having a clear understanding of your requirements, existing systems, ... it is not possible to give specific advice on such details. The best you can hope for ... would be more or less opinion based answers. The single possible "answer" is: **you** should analyse the two patterns in depth; and decide which one better fits your needs. And most likely, such sophisticated system will eventually use many different patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Factory is to make your object creation easier and maintainable.

Facade is to make your your subsytem simpler by defining a higher level interface, rather than having to deal with many classes and methods.

If your requirement needs both, you could use both patterns.